# swscanf_s - run-time check error

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm trying to use the "secure" swscanf_s to parse a string. The following console code (Visual Studio 2017, extracted from a much bigger program) compiles OK and appears to parse the string **buf** OK (rv = 4 and the variables are filled in correctly), but I get a run-time error message as soon as the function exits.

```
int main()
{
    TCHAR buf[] = L"100 200 a 3.5";
    int i1, i2;
    double d;
    wchar_t c;
    int rv = swscanf_s(buf, L"%d %d %1ws %lf", &i1, &i2, &c, (unsigned)sizeof(c), &d);
    return 0;
}
```

The message is:
**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'c' was corrupted.**

The problem certainly lies in reading the wide character 'a' since if I take that out everything works OK, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure there's a simple answer, but any help would be appreciated.

SOLVED: (maybe delete question?) I was using %1ws in the format string because of the Microsoft documentation stating "White-space characters that are ordinarily skipped are read when c is specified. To read next non-white-space single-byte character, use %1s; to read next non-white-space wide character, use %1ws.". However, when I just used %c, the character was read OK (as 'a', not ' '), and the run-time error went away. Confusing!

Comment: `wchar_t c;` there's moar space needed.

Comment: `%ws` stores a string (null-terminated), so it always needs an array with 1 more allocated element. I think you want to use `%wc` (single character) instead?

Comment: _"maybe delete question?"_ Yes, it turned out to be a very simple if not trivial problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the length, but you're passing the size instead.

The size of a wide character is 2 bytes, so `(unsigned)sizeof(c)` is 2, but you should pass the length in characters, meaning 1.

Also, I'm not sure, but I think you need enough space for a terminating null as well (since you're reading a string).